# Springboot , tomcat 8 , can't find driver for Postgres

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot, tomcat8

I am using a spring boot applicaiton with Postgres.

But i can't get it running without adding my postgres.jar to the lib in the tomcat.

Are there any possibility to just use the postgres jar that i added within my application.

Realy want to issolate all my jar dependencies to my war and not change my Tomcat.

What i understand is it uses the the tomcat pooling for my application, are there any way to disable this?

This is my pom

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-processing</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


       <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-tools-common</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-simple</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test
spring.datasource.username=dbuser
spring.datasource.password=dbpass
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

Comment: Please add your datasource configuration.

Comment: I am assuming you havent add postgres jar to maven dependency. Please can you post your pom and jdbc config if this is not what you are looking for

Comment: Check this example configuration pom.xml - add dependency for postgresql driver - https://github.com/AlgiersJUG/spring-boot-postgres-sample/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: I have added my pom dependencies

Comment: Please can you provide full POM

Comment: I added my boot config which works with MYSQL for me. http://pastebin.com/SderHTg5

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the postgres.jar as a dependency in your pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: While this might be correct, OP doesn't anywhere specify that he uses maven as his dependency/build framework.

Comment: I use maven and i have the dependency in my pom,

Comment: Please remove  <version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</version> from your pom. Spring-boot will automatically resolve the version for you. Though I really doubt if that will help you.

Comment: <dependency>
                <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>